# Can I post messages from page directly to extension's background script w/o content-script in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I created a simple chrome extension that adds some functionality to my webPage (site), that is only accessible via extension. Is it possible to postMessages directly from webpage (**NOT** via `content-script`) to extension's **background-script**. And if it's not, what is the use-case of `chrome.runtime.connect(EXTENSION_ID);`, I mean why it's accessible from web-page?

Code bellow represents how I communicate between my page and extension. It doesn't work, `onConnect.addListener` doesn't trigger in myExtension, `port.onMessage` doesn't trigger in myExtension nor in my webPage.

[image]

**https://localhost:8000/myPage.html**:

```js
var port = chrome.runtime.connect("ppibnonicgkeojloifobdloaiajedhgg"); // this is extensionId I got from chrome://extension
port.onMessage.addListener(function (event) { 
    console.log(event);
});
port.postMessage({type: 'PYCHAT_SCREEN_SHARE_PING', text: 'start'});
```

**background.js** from my extension:

```js
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
  console.log("Connected from new port ", port);
  port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    console.log("Got new message ", msg);
    port.postMessage({type: "PYCHAT_SCREEN_SHARE_PING_RESPONSE", data: "successs"});
  });
});
```

**manifest.json**:

```json
{
  "name": "test",
  "description": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "desktopCapture",
    "tabs"
  ],
}
```

Comment: See [messaging documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage): you need to list the web site URL in `externally_connectable`.

Comment: @wOxxOm does `externally_connectable` work only with `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` or it's suitable for `port` as well? I added `externally_connectable` to my `manifest.json` but port still doesn't trigger callbacks.

Comment: `The URL pattern must contain at least a second-level domain` - it means you'll have to add an alias into your `/etc/hosts` e.g. `127.0.0.1 foo.bar.com`. Also reload the extension on chrome://extensions page.

Comment: @wOxxOm doesn't work, could you please take a look, I edited my answer according your guide. I open page from 'https://test-pychat.org:8000/`,  I also use self-assigned certificate for https.

Comment: @wOxxOm  `chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal` + `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` works, but I really would like to communicate using port.

Comment: See [Using chrome.runtime.sendmessage to communicate from a webpage to a packaged app](//stackoverflow.com/a/23585105)

Comment: As the documentation says, you should use `onConnectExternal` instead of `onConnect`

Comment: Thank you, `onConnectExternal` worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @wOxxOm @rsanchez I should:

- Use `chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal` in background.js
- Add `externally_connectable` to manifest.json

https://localhost:8000:

```
var port = chrome.runtime.connect("ppibnonicgkeojloifobdloaiajedhgg"); 
port.onMessage.addListener(function (event) { 
    console.log(event);
});
port.postMessage({type: 'PYCHAT_SCREEN_SHARE_PING', text: 'start'});
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "description": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "desktopCapture",
    "tabs"
  ],
  "externally_connectable": {
    "matches": ["https://localhost:8000"] 
  }
}
```

**background.js**:

```
chrome.runtime.onConnectExternal.addListener(function(port) {
  port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    console.log("it works")
    port.postMessage({type: "PYCHAT_SCREEN_SHARE_PING_RESPONSE", data: "successs"});
  });
});
```